# interpretation of yum error messages

Tags: linux, centos, php, yum, rpm

I tried to upgrade php 5 to php 7 on CentOS6 but failed with errors like this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-7.3.16-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php(api) = 20180731-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-50.el6_10.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-7.3.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php(api) = 20180731-64
```

I guess it says some package is dependent on some package that is being removed, but I cannot understand exactly what the error messages are meaning. Can anybody please explain the error messages to me, line by line? Is there any document that describes yum output messages? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What are the enabled repositories (yum repolist) ?

What is the exact command run and full output ?

Please read [About libmcrypt and php-mcrypt](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

If you properly follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) and have enabled the **remi-php73** repository permanently, this should work (and pull **php-pecl-mcrypt** package).

```
# yum install php-mcrypt
...
Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================
 Package                Arch          Version                        Repository         Size
=============================================================================================
Installing:
 php-pecl-mcrypt        x86_64        1.0.3-1.el6.remi.7.3           remi-php73         27 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libmcrypt              x86_64        2.5.8-9.el6                    epel               96 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
```

Again, the [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) extension is dead, and should NOT be used. This package is only available to allow legacy applications.

Comment: thank you for the information. I'm following the instructions but get similar errors when running "yum update"(this time for the phpMyAdmin package). If I use "yum update --skip-broken", it pulls a lot of packages(135M in total). I am afraid of breaking existing software if I install all of them. I would like to know the exact meaning of the error messages so I can selectively remove/reinstall some of the conflicting packages. I just want to upgrade php, not all of my system.

Comment: If I run "yum update php", I also get similar errors: "Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel), Error: Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-50.el6_10.x86_64 (updates), Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch (epel)"

Comment: Not enough information, need the "full" yum output.

Comment: Also check if "priority" plugin is enabled, and for phpMyAdmin you need "remi" as version in EPEL is too old and not compatible with recent PHP versions